# PowerShell 2.0 String character issues and Get-Content Replace

Tags: regex, string, powershell

I was wondering if anyone could add to this issue I'm having with backslashes?

Unfortunately, my current work environment is on PowerShell 2.0 and who knows when they will move to 4.0.  So there are somethings that I wrote when I worked somewhere else in PowerShell 4.0 that won't work in 2.0,

In Powershell 4.0, this would work with no issues. But not in 2.0.

(gc C:\Temp\Test.reg).Replace("HKEY_USERS\$PROFILENAME", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER")|sc C:\Temp\Test.reg

So I tried this, when writing this in 2.0, I have no luck.

(gc C:\Temp\Test.reg") foreach { $_ -replace "HKEY_USERS\$PROFILENAME", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"} |sc C:\Temp\Test.reg")

This will work as long as I don't have a "\" in it.  The script sees it as a system.object and won't touch the backslash.  Is there a way to replace "HKEY_USERS\$PROFILENAME" with just "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"

This is frustrating.....

Comment: Never mind, I figured out a way to do it. I had to use two backslashes and then it worked.  Sorry guys.

(gc C:\Temp\Test.reg") foreach { $_ -replace "HKEY_USERS\\$PROFILENAME", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"} |sc C:\Temp\Test.reg")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslash is an escape char in regex within powershell.  Use double the backslashes in the regex portion.

`(gc C:\Temp\Test.reg).Replace("HKEY_USERS\\$PROFILENAME", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER")|sc C:\Temp\Test.reg`